# Como cadastrar dados sempre no ultimo document gerado?

Tags: java, android, firestore

No meu código toda vez que vou realizar um cadastro um `document` é criado. Gostaria de saber se tem como cadastrar informações neste ultimo `document` gerado em vez de gerar outro. Estou fazendo em Java, usando o Cloud Firestore.

```
  db.collection("enfermeiros").document()
                            .set(enfermeiro, SetOptions.merge())
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "DEU BOM");
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "DEU MERDA", e);
                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Eu faço assim:**

```
firestoreMetas
.collection("metas_compras")
.document(metaCompra.id_meta)
.set(metaCompra)
.addOnSuccessListener {
    //Sucesso 
}.addOnFailureListener{
    //Erro
}
```

Bom, basicamente, uso o **id** do **document** (metas) que eu quero, e passo um objeto (metaCompra) com as novas informações.

Espero ter ajudado...

Comment: Do jeito que vc sugeriu as informações vao ser cadastradas num id especifico(No ID que vc quer )?

Comment: Isso, pelo que entendi, você não quer criar um novo document, quer salvar as informações no que já está criado certo? Então, você usa o Id do que está criado e salva as novas informações nele.

Comment: na verdade oque eu queria era criar um document e cadastrar nele e repetir o processo a cada vez que for realizar um cadastro, cada vez num document diferente.